# filerering / replacing single quote in java

Tags: java, jsp

How do I filter single  quotes ' in java?

I have a search box where if anyone types a single quote, I get a database error.

I don't want to filet it in JavaScript or at Database level; I want to do it in Java only. How can I do that?

I don't want to lose it completely. Is there any other way? Will replacing the quote with \' work??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle. I strongly suspect you're building your SQL like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USERID='" + userInput + "'";
```

or something similar. Don't do that. Use a parameterized query instead, and supply the user input as the parameter. Every database I've ever used knows how to handle that, and it's the *safe* way to handle user input.

If you *really, really* just want to get rid of quotes, you can use:

```
text = text.replace("'", "");
```

... but please don't. Use a parameterized query instead.

Comment: i cant do that i am using hibernate, so i want to do filtering in java itsel andnot at db level

Comment: i dont want to loose it completely, is there any other way. wil replacing the quote with \' wil work??

Comment: If you're using Hibernate, you shouldn't need to do this. It uses prepared statements itself, precisely to avoid SQL injections (and to improve performance). Please edit your question to give an example of how you're trying to execute the query, and we should be able to help.

Comment: i want to do that in java only plz

Comment: I'll second Jon Skeets answer. If you're using hibernate correctly, you shouldn't be getting any errors like this.

Comment: i have to submit my project tmmoro so i cant do major changes now . i just want to filter quote in java

Comment: You shouldn't need to make major changes. Filtering quotes yourself is the *wrong* approach. Show us some code, and we should be able to help you fix it quickly. Hibernate is *designed* for this not to be a problem.

Comment: As previously said, the gist of the problem is that you're most likely trying to build an SQL statement by concatenating strings. This is very bad practice, and if you're instructor is good she'll mark you down for it. Use kd304's solution with PreparedStatement. It does exactly what you want. I promise that it won't take till tomorrow to implement.

Also, what's the point of the assignment? If this is a hibernate exercise, you probably won't score any points by using it incorrectly.

Comment: @Mike: If the OP is using Hibernate already, then changing to use a direct PreparedStatement wouldn't be ideal. Hibernate does the right thing normally, so we need to find out why the OP is seeing a problem. Then we can hopefully fix it in a way which fits with the rest of the application design. There's no need to change database access mechanism from Hibernate just to get around this.

Comment: +1 for not doing it in code under any circumstances. No, no, never.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use PreparedStatement.setString():

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE USERID = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, "O'Connor");
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Escaping rules for databases differ. For example in Oracle you can duplicate the apostrope to get it escaped. In MySQL it is backslash + apostrophe (I think).

So either `userInput = userInput.replaceAll("'", "''");` or `userInput = userInput.replaceAll("'", "\\'");`